# Create keybindings for a specific buffer(s)

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-fugitive

I'd like to create keybindings that would only work in fugitive buffer, e.g. `gp` to run `:G pull` and `gP` to run `:G push` (frankly, it's kind of strange that there are no default shortcuts for this in fugitive itself, am I missing something?). How can I do this?

Comment: I don’t think you’re missing anything. Trying to keep straight which p is pull or push would be hard for me, and maybe Tim Pope decided it would confuse most people, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fugitive uses an own filetype you can make use of.

within your configuration directory, within the directory `ftplugin` create the following file:

`ftplugin/fugitive.vim` with the content of:

```
nnoremap <buffer> gp :G pull<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> gP :G push<CR>
```

Restart and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use an autcmd in your `~/.vimrc` (but maybe shouldn't—see footnote below):

```
augroup CustomFugitiveMappings
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType fugitive nmap <buffer> gp :G pull<CR>
  autocmd FileType fugitive nmap <buffer> gP :G push<CR>
augroup END
```

Some references:

- [Autocommand Groups / Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html)
- [Vim documentation: autocmd](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)
- [tpope comment on Issue #1425 · tpope/vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1425#issuecomment-902418823)

<strike>I think this approach is equivalent to the ftplugin approach; use this if you prefer to keep all your custom config in your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/init.vim`, or use the ftplugin approach if you prefer a modular config.</strike>

EDIT: see comment below from @romainl; the ftplugin approach is preferred.

Comment: No, this is not equivalent. First because you are adding two more autocommands while the ftplugin approach doesn't. Sure that's only two, but if you do that for every filetype-specific mapping or option it will add up for no good reason. Second, because doing your filetype-specific stuff in a regular ftplugin allows you to define script-local functions to be used in mappings/commands, for example. Vim tries to source a ftplugin anyway so it makes the most sense to just use it.

Comment: Thanks @romainl